# How to count results in subqueries

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm implementing movies database.
I have tables: `movies`, `people`, `movie_people`, `awards`. Both `people` and `movies` have field with id of award, which can be `NULL`. 
I can't get how to make SQL query which prints out list of actors, who played in movies, which were directed by directors who have 3 or more awards?

```
CREATE TABLE "LAB"."MOVIE" 
   (    "MOVIE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(219 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "YEARMADE" DATE, 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "RUNNINGTIME" NUMBER, 
    "LANGUAGE" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "TAG_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REVIEW_ID" NUMBER, 
    "AWARD_ID" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("MOVIE_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     FOREIGN KEY ("TAG_ID")
      REFERENCES "LAB"."TAG" ("TAG_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
     FOREIGN KEY ("REVIEW_ID")
      REFERENCES "LAB"."REVIEW" ("REVIEW_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "AWARD_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("AWARD_ID")
      REFERENCES "LAB"."AWARD" ("AWARD_ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE TABLE "LAB"."MOVIE_PEOPLE" 
   (    "MOVIE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PEOPLE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROLE" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     FOREIGN KEY ("MOVIE_ID")
      REFERENCES "LAB"."MOVIE" ("MOVIE_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
     FOREIGN KEY ("PEOPLE_ID")
      REFERENCES "LAB"."PEOPLE" ("PEOPLE_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE TABLE "LAB"."PEOPLE" 
   (    "PEOPLE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FAMILYNAME" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GIVENNAME" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GENDER" CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATEOFBIRTH" DATE, 
    "TAG_ID" NUMBER, 
    "AWARD_ID" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("PEOPLE_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     FOREIGN KEY ("TAG_ID")
      REFERENCES "LAB"."TAG" ("TAG_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
     FOREIGN KEY ("AWARD_ID")
      REFERENCES "LAB"."AWARD" ("AWARD_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE TABLE "LAB"."AWARD" 
   (    "AWARD_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "YEAR" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("AWARD_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Comment: Check with @mboronin - [his question about homework against this very same schema can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888888/how-to-make-this-query-in-oracle/30889864#30889864).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) statement in SQL, that way you can filter only the directors with 3 or more awards.

**UPDATE**

Also you will need to add a `FOREIGN KEY` with the director id to the awards. Unless an award can belong to multiple people, then you have to create a relation table.

Comment: you can join awards on director and use count(*) aggregation, but therefore each award needs a director_id so you know which director the award belongs to.